# How to output the 3 most frequent pattern matches in sorted order in the Linux terminal?

Tags: linux, unix, terminal

I have a file called `survey.txt` in which I used `cut -d, -f1 survey.csv`  to get the following result:

```
What's your favorite candy?
Skittles
Butterfinger
Skittles
Snickers
100 grand
Chocolate
See's Candies
Twix
Sour patch
Sour Patch Kids
Dark chocolate
Reese's Take 5
FERRERO ROCHER
butterfinger
M&M
Twix
twix
I don't like candy that much.
kit kat
Gummy Bears
Sour Patch Kids
skittles
KitKats
Twix
Sour patch - Watermelon
White Rabbit creamy candy
Crunch
Anything savory!
not in favor of candies
skittles
right Twix
M&M's
Skittles
M&Ms
any chocolate
Kit Kat
Reeses
KitKats
Sour Patch Kids
Sourpatch kids
M&M's
Nerds
M&Ms
Mars Bars
Jolly Ranchers
swedish fish
hichew
Reece's
M&Ms
cane
KitKat
Sour Patch Kids
strawberry cream chocolate
Anything dark chocolate
Reeses
KitKat or Sour Gummies of any kind.
Blue Raspberry Laffy Taffy
Nerds
Milk chocolate
kit kat
Chocolate
Kit Kat
Twix
Warheads
Twix
Skittles
Zotz
Crunch Bars
Gummy Bears
Sour patch kids
swedish fish
I really like mints
Twix
I don't like candy
Sour gummy worms
Buncha Crunch
Cotton candy
Reeses
Airheads
Jolly Ranchers  or any other clear  sweet or sour candy
I'm more of a gum person
Chocolate bar!
Sour patch kids
Chocolate
Sour Patch!
Mike and Ike
sour punches
Ice Cream Mochi
skittles
Reeses
Toffee
Nerds
Sour gummy worms
Gummy bears
chocolate
gummy candy
Twix
oreos
Kit Kat
Haribo gummy bears
Pretzel M&M's
jolly ranchers
Skittles
M&M
Pulse (Indian Mango flavored candy)
mm
Rips
```

What I am trying to do now is to find out what are the three most common answers to the question "What's your favorite candy?" (case-insensitive). I am trying to format my output in the following way (XX is the count):

```
XX Candy1
XX Candy2
XX Candy3
```

I tried using `grep`, but I'm completely unsure how to count every instance and output the three most popular answers in sorted order. I'm still relatively new to the Linux terminal. I appreciate any advice or feedback to help me understand Linux commands better.

Comment: `sort result | uniq -c | sort -n | tail -n 3`

Comment: Wow, within seconds of each other! Except your answer sorts in the opposite order

Comment: Yup. And you're getting minus-points for needless use of `cat` ;)

Comment: Oh, man, lets be friends instead. I will follow your suggestion, because you are right

Comment: When learning how each of the commands work, take them one-by-one. Look at the output of `sort result` and see shat is being piped to `uniq -c`, and so on and so forth...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
$ sort -f survey.txt | uniq -ic | sort -nr | head -n 3
      7 Twix
      5 Skittles
      4 Sour Patch Kids
```

### How it works

There are four computational steps above, with 3 pipes connecting chained input to chained output.

1. An alphabetic sort is applied to the contents of `survey.txt`
2. Duplicate consecutive lines were removed with `uniq` and a count of how many duplicates were found is inserted as the first field/column.
3. A numeric sort was applied, in reverse. This ordered the results properly.
4. The first three lines were kept with `head` and the rest were discarded.

Comment: What about case insensitive? For instance there's 'Kit Kat' and 'kit kat'

Comment: Weird that the option flags for `sort` and `uniq`  case insensitivity are different.

Comment: If case sensitivity is a concern, you would be better served using `awk` for the frequency analysis.

Comment: Already done and done. No problem.